# Instantiate & pass C++ object to Node.js function V8

Tags: c++, node.js, asynchronous, v8, cvv8

I would like to be able to instantiate an instance of a C++ class and pass it as an argument to a JavaScript callback. The class inherits from `ObjectWrap`, and is available to and used in Node.js.

I am able to pass instances of the same class to the callback if said instance *came from JavaScript*.

This is a basic example of what I need to do:

```
MyClass *instance = new MyClass();

// If was passed as the first param to this method, commit is set as below, this code works.
// MyClass *instance = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<MyClass>(args[0]->ToObject());

// Assign some property values to commit
Handle<Value> argv[] = { instance->handle_ };
ar->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 1, argv);
```

This doesn't work, instead it segfaults. `gdb` tells me:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
```

How might I modify my code to allow me to pass my `instance` to the callback?

---

**Update**: the class in question may be viewed on Github: [commit.cc](https://github.com/tbranyen/nodegit/blob/master/src/commit.cc).

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the whole class? Surely you can find a cleaner way to communicate between node and C++? 

Maybe you can design your project so the C++ program outputs the data you need to stdin and your js program takes it from stdin.

Comment: Because the module wraps the functionality of a library. What you suggest is not an option.

Comment: You should instanciate your object from C++ with MyClass::New that you probably defined as the Constructor. Otherwise, you handle_ reference is not initiated.

Comment: Thanks @Floby, in my use case, what should I pass as `&args`? https://github.com/tbranyen/nodegit/blob/master/src/commit.cc#L105?

Comment: a v8::Arguments object that contains the JS parameters

Comment: @Floby in this case there aren't any, I'm instantiating this object form the `afterwork` method for `uv_queue_work`

Comment: then empty arguments array it is

Comment: @Floby this results in an empty object being passed to JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that I was doing it wrong.

The correct code:

```
Local<Value> instance = MyClass::constructor_template->NewInstance();

// Assign some property values to commit
Handle<Value> argv[] = { instance };
ar->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 1, argv);
```

To get the `MyClass` instance:

```
MyClass *instanceOfMyClass = ObjectWrap::Unwrap(instance);
```